# Issues with javascript async and twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter

I currently have code and functions(shown below) for getting tweets and then looking through the tweet data to return the most used words in the collection. My question is how to run the code in an async way? so far I have tried `getTweets().done(getTopwords());` but this simply returns undefined, I'm unsure if this is an issue with my code or that this isn't having the desired effect. Each individual function works on its own.

EDIT:

My understanding is that `getTweets().done(getTopwords());` calls `getTweets()` and when this has finished calls `getTopwords()`.

CODE:

```
// placeholder variables
var profile = 'MCFC',
    keyword = '',
    count = 10,
    date = '2015-11-11',
    lan = 'en',
    search = keyword + " since:" + date + " lang:" + lan,
    tweettxt = [],
    users = [];

// function for searching through twitter using the specified data
function getTweets(){
  return client.get('search/tweets', { q: search, count: count, from: profile },
              handleTweets)
}

// function for handling the tweets
function handleTweets(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }  
  else {
    return sortTweets(data);
  }
}

// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
      changedString = string.replace(/,/g, " "), // remove the array elements 
      split = changedString.split(" "), // split the string 
      words = []; // array for the words

  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
      words[split[i]]=1;
    } else {
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}

// function for returning the top 20 words from getFreqword()
function getTopwords(){
  var topwords = getFreqword(),
      toptwenty = [];

  for (var i=0; i<=20; i++){
    toptwenty.push(topwords[i])
    toptwenty.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  }
  return toptwenty
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
// function for sorting through the tweets to return relevant information
function sortTweets (data) {
  for (var indx in data.statuses){
    var tweet = data.statuses[indx];
    tweettxt.push(tweet.text); // push the tweet text so it can be sorted for the most frequent words
    users.push(tweet.user.screen_name); // push the twitter user screen name so it can be sorted to find the most frequent users
  }
}
```

Comment: where is code for `sortTweets()` function?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: And how or where you are calling `getTweets()`?

Comment: just with a line within the file consoe.log(getTweets().done(getTopwords()));

Comment: You are interested in `toptwenty` returned from `getTopwords()` and you want to set function execution order right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
// placeholder variables
var profile = 'MCFC',
  keyword = '',
  count = 10,
  date = '2015-11-11',
  lan = 'en',
  search = keyword + " since:" + date + " lang:" + lan,
  tweettxt = [],
  users = [];

// function for searching through twitter using the specified data
function getTweets(){
  client.get('search/tweets', {
    q: search,
    count: count,
    from: profile
  },
  handleTweets);
}

// function for handling the tweets
function handleTweets(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.error('Get error', err)
  }
  else{
    sortTweets(data);

    /* call getTopwords() as we sorted tweets */
    toptwenty = getTopwords();

    /* now you can access toptwenty */
    console.log(toptwenty);
  }
}

// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
    changedString = string.replace(/,/g, " "), // remove the array elements 
    split = changedString.split(" "), // split the string 
    words = []; // array for the words

  for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]] === undefined){
      words[split[i]] = 1;
    }else{
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}

// function for returning the top 20 words from getFreqword()
function getTopwords(){
  var topwords = getFreqword(),
    toptwenty = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    toptwenty.push(topwords[i])
    toptwenty.sort(function(a, b){
      return a - b
    });
  }
  return toptwenty
}

// function for sorting through the tweets to return relevant information
function sortTweets(data){
  for(var indx in data.statuses){
    var tweet = data.statuses[indx];
    tweettxt.push(tweet.text); // push the tweet text so it can be sorted for the most frequent words
    users.push(tweet.user.screen_name); // push the twitter user screen name so it can be sorted to find the most frequent users
  }
}

getTweets();
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, I have made the changes you have suggested and this is the output I am getting: [ 1,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ], the output when tested on placeholder variables is { hello: 50, bye: 36 }

Comment: This is as per you logic not just by execution order of functions; check your logic again;

Comment: I believe an issue is that the inital array containing the collection of frequent words isnt sorted before pushing the top twenty words. However I now encounter topword.sort isnt a funtion. As far as I am aware from running node-debug topwords is and array so I am unsure why it cant be sorted?